# Pygame.rect x and y values not accesible

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame

So i was following a pygame tutorial and after showing the sprites and scaling the with the `pygame.image.load()` and the `pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale))` he then makes some rectangles in the main() function and gets the x and y values to use in another fuction. But my game crashes.

```
def draw_window(yellow, red):
    WIN.fill(BACKGROUND)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, (700, 300))
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, (100, 300))
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    yellow = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    red = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
```

Also I get the error

> TypeError: draw_window() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'yellow' and 'red'

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, you must pass the arguments to the function.
The argument can be anything and the name of the passed variables does not need to match the name of the formal parameters. Also see [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

```py
def draw_window(yellow_ship_rect, red_ship_rect):
    WIN.fill(BACKGROUND)
    WIN.blit(YELLOW_SPACESHIP, yellow_ship_rect)
    WIN.blit(RED_SPACESHIP, red_ship_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

```py
def main():
    yellow = pygame.Rect(700, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)
    red = pygame.Rect(100, 300, SPACESHIP_WIDTH, SPACESHIP_HEIGHT)

    # [...]

    while run:
        # [...]

        draw_window(yellow, red)
```